Apexcharts кнопки зума исчезают
На странице я использую несколько графиков созданых с помощью Apexcharts, на одном из графиков добавлены кнопки форматированого зума

как только я нажимаю на одну из кнопок, либо же на любой другой фильтр который так же присутствует на графике - кнопки указаные на картинке исчезают.

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@aleksandr-barakin Александр, я бы с удовольствием добавил тэг apexchart, но для этого нужны 300 балов репутации. поиски в гугле или же на форуме дают массу ответов но для чартов интегрированых в ВП

три вопроса за три года, помимо вашего - не думаю, что такая низкая активность требует создания отдельной метки.
